# Java Output if and else?

Tags: java, if-statement

I want to lexiographically arrange my strings.  My code also works. But when I enter the strings Hans, Anna and Max he gives me both the "if" and the "else" println. Where is the error?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ersteAufgabe {

public static void main(String args[]) {

          Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
          String s1 = scan.nextLine();
          String s2 = scan.nextLine();
          String s3 = scan.nextLine();
          if (s1.compareTo(s2) < 0 & s1.compareTo(s3) < 0 & s2.compareTo(s1) > 0 & s2.compareTo(s3) < 0 & s3.compareTo(s1) > 0 & s3.compareTo(s2) > 0) 
          {
            System.out.println("Ordnung:" + s1 +" "+ s2 +" " + s3);  
          }
          if (s1.compareTo(s2) < 0 & s1.compareTo(s3) < 0 & s2.compareTo(s1) > 0 & s2.compareTo(s3) > 0 & s3.compareTo(s1) > 0 & s3.compareTo(s2) < 0) 
          {
            System.out.println("Ordnung:" + s1 +" "+ s3 +" " + s2);  
          }
          if (s1.compareTo(s2) > 0 & s1.compareTo(s3) < 0 & s2.compareTo(s3) < 0 & s2.compareTo(s1) < 0 & s3.compareTo(s1) > 0 & s3.compareTo(s2) > 0) 
          {
            System.out.println("Ordnung:" + s2 +" "+ s1 +" " + s3);  
          }
          if (s1.compareTo(s2) > 0 & s1.compareTo(s3) > 0 & s2.compareTo(s1) < 0 & s2.compareTo(s3) < 0 & s3.compareTo(s1) < 0 & s3.compareTo(s2) > 0) 
          {
            System.out.println("Ordnung:" + s2 +" "+ s3 +" " + s1);  
          }
          if (s1.compareTo(s2) < 0 & s1.compareTo(s3) > 0 & s2.compareTo(s3) > 0 & s2.compareTo(s1) > 0 & s3.compareTo(s1) < 0 & s3.compareTo(s2) < 0)
          {
            System.out.println("Ordnung:" + s3 +" "+ s1 +" " + s2);  
          }
          if (s1.compareTo(s2) > 0 & s1.compareTo(s3) > 0 & s2.compareTo(s1) < 0 & s2.compareTo(s3) > 0 & s3.compareTo(s2) < 0 & s3.compareTo(s1) < 0)
          {
            System.out.println("Ordnung:" + s3 +" "+ s2 +" " + s1);  
          } else{
              System.out.println("Ungueltige Eingabe");
          }

    }
 }
```

Comment: `Stream.of("Hans, Anna, Max".split("\\s*,\\s*")).sorted().forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: IS there a reason for not using Java built-ins like `SortedSet`, `Collections::sort`, etc. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `else` in your code is only connected to the last `if`. That means that if one of the other `if`s is true (and the last `if` is false), the `else` is executed as well. So try this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

          Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
          String s1 = scan.nextLine();
          String s2 = scan.nextLine();
          String s3 = scan.nextLine();
          if (s1.compareTo(s2) < 0 & s1.compareTo(s3) < 0 & s2.compareTo(s1) > 0 & s2.compareTo(s3) < 0 & s3.compareTo(s1) > 0 & s3.compareTo(s2) > 0) 
          {
            System.out.println("Ordnung:" + s1 +" "+ s2 +" " + s3);  
          }
          else if (s1.compareTo(s2) < 0 & s1.compareTo(s3) < 0 & s2.compareTo(s1) > 0 & s2.compareTo(s3) > 0 & s3.compareTo(s1) > 0 & s3.compareTo(s2) < 0) 
          {
            System.out.println("Ordnung:" + s1 +" "+ s3 +" " + s2);  
          }
          else if (s1.compareTo(s2) > 0 & s1.compareTo(s3) < 0 & s2.compareTo(s3) < 0 & s2.compareTo(s1) < 0 & s3.compareTo(s1) > 0 & s3.compareTo(s2) > 0) 
          {
            System.out.println("Ordnung:" + s2 +" "+ s1 +" " + s3);  
          }
          else if (s1.compareTo(s2) > 0 & s1.compareTo(s3) > 0 & s2.compareTo(s1) < 0 & s2.compareTo(s3) < 0 & s3.compareTo(s1) < 0 & s3.compareTo(s2) > 0) 
          {
            System.out.println("Ordnung:" + s2 +" "+ s3 +" " + s1);  
          }
          else if (s1.compareTo(s2) < 0 & s1.compareTo(s3) > 0 & s2.compareTo(s3) > 0 & s2.compareTo(s1) > 0 & s3.compareTo(s1) < 0 & s3.compareTo(s2) < 0)
          {
            System.out.println("Ordnung:" + s3 +" "+ s1 +" " + s2);  
          }
          else if (s1.compareTo(s2) > 0 & s1.compareTo(s3) > 0 & s2.compareTo(s1) < 0 & s2.compareTo(s3) > 0 & s3.compareTo(s2) < 0 & s3.compareTo(s1) < 0)
          {
            System.out.println("Ordnung:" + s3 +" "+ s2 +" " + s1);  
          } else{
              System.out.println("Ungueltige Eingabe");
          }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a series of `if`s that are all independent other than the last one which is attached to your `else`. If you want that last `else` to act as an `else` for the entire chain, you need to convert your intermediate `if`s to `if else`s.

```
if (condition1) {
    // Do something...
} else if (condition2) {
    // Do something else...
} else {
    // Do something if neither condition1 nor condition2
}
```

*Side note*: I see that you're using the bitwise and operator (`&`) instead of the boolean and operator (`&&`). Though it may work in your case, I would highly caution you against using bitwise operator for anything other than bitwise manipulation because it has a higher precedence than inequalities, whereas boolean operators have a lower precedence which may lead to unintended results.

Answer (score 0):

You need need change your control statement to,

```
 if (s1.compareTo(s2) < 0 & s1.compareTo(s3) < 0 & s2.compareTo(s1) > 0 & s2.compareTo(s3) < 0 & s3.compareTo(s1) > 0 & s3.compareTo(s2) > 0) {
            System.out.println("Ordnung:" + s1 + " " + s2 + " " + s3);
        }
        else if (s1.compareTo(s2) < 0 & s1.compareTo(s3) < 0 & s2.compareTo(s1) > 0 & s2.compareTo(s3) > 0 & s3.compareTo(s1) > 0 & s3.compareTo(s2) < 0) {
            System.out.println("Ordnung:" + s1 + " " + s3 + " " + s2);
        }
        else if (s1.compareTo(s2) > 0 & s1.compareTo(s3) < 0 & s2.compareTo(s3) < 0 & s2.compareTo(s1) < 0 & s3.compareTo(s1) > 0 & s3.compareTo(s2) > 0) {
            System.out.println("Ordnung:" + s2 + " " + s1 + " " + s3);
        }
        else if (s1.compareTo(s2) > 0 & s1.compareTo(s3) > 0 & s2.compareTo(s1) < 0 & s2.compareTo(s3) < 0 & s3.compareTo(s1) < 0 & s3.compareTo(s2) > 0) {
            System.out.println("Ordnung:" + s2 + " " + s3 + " " + s1);
        }
        else if (s1.compareTo(s2) < 0 & s1.compareTo(s3) > 0 & s2.compareTo(s3) > 0 & s2.compareTo(s1) > 0 & s3.compareTo(s1) < 0 & s3.compareTo(s2) < 0) {
            System.out.println("Ordnung:" + s3 + " " + s1 + " " + s2);
        }
        else if (s1.compareTo(s2) > 0 & s1.compareTo(s3) > 0 & s2.compareTo(s1) < 0 & s2.compareTo(s3) > 0 & s3.compareTo(s2) < 0 & s3.compareTo(s1) < 0) {
            System.out.println("Ordnung:" + s3 + " " + s2 + " " + s1);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Ungueltige Eingabe");
        }
```

So that only one of them gets executed. What you have currently is multiple unrelated if statements!